# Export row to PDF/ Word using cell number selected in a dropdown

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the code below to export a row in an Excel sheet into a Word/pdf file.

It is downloading all non-blank rows.

I want when I select a reference number in a cell dropdown ("CA2"), it only downloads that selected row.

```
Sub Download_Click()

Dim CustRow, CustCol, LastRow, TemplRow, Reference, RefRow As Long
Dim DocLoc, TagName, TagValue, TemplName, FileName As String
Dim CurDt, LastAppDt As Date
Dim WordDoc, WordApp, OutApp, OutMail As Object
Dim WordContent As Word.Range

With Sheet3

    TemplRow = .Range("CI1").Value
    TemplName = .Range("BV2").Value
    Reference = .Range("CA2").Value
    DocLoc = Sheet3.Range("CG2").Value

    On Error Resume Next
    Set WordApp = GetObject("Word.Application")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        WordApp.Visible = True
    End If

    LastRow = .Range("A9999").End(xlUp).Row
    For CustRow = 3 To LastRow
        Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(FileName:=DocLoc, ReadOnly:=False)
        For CustCol = 1 To 70
            TagName = .Cells(2, CustCol).Value
            TagValue = .Cells(CustRow, CustCol).Value
            With WordDoc.Content.Find
                .Text = TagName
                .Replacement.Text = TagValue
                .Wrap = wdFindContinue
                .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
            End With
        Next CustCol

        If .Range("BX2").Value = "PDF" Then
            FileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & .Range("B" & CustRow).Value & "_" & .Range("C" & CustRow).Value & ".pdf"
            WordDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:=FileName, ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF
            WordDoc.Close False
        Else
            FileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & .Range("B" & CustRow).Value & "_" & .Range("C" & CustRow).Value & ".docx"
            WordDoc.SaveAs FileName
        End If
    Next CustRow
    WordApp.Quit

End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand now, your code will export all rows from row 3 to the last row:

```
For CustRow = 3 To LastRow
```

If you want only a selected row to be exported, then all you need to do is remove that loop and replace it with a single value, so it only runs once for that value. Remove the above line and replace with this:

```
CustRow = .Range("CA2").Value
```

Make sure to remove `Next CustRow`. Also make sure that cell `CA2` contains a numerical value which is a direct reference to the row you need.

Comment: Thanks for that.  One quick comment to add to that, my reference "1" begins on row 3 which is the first custrow.

Comment: To accomodate that, you can just add 2 to the value as so: `Custrow = .Range("CA2").value + 2` which means value 1 becomes 3, so starts on row 3. This also acts as a filter for non-numeric values, as `"text"+2` returns an error.

Comment: No problem, here to help. Feel free to accept my answer if it has solved your problem, or let me know if there are any more issues with this solution.

Comment: New to this, so wasn't aware of that feature. Done now anyway. Thanks again!

Comment: Cheers, and no problem, we were all new here once.